# Make a series of dropdowns non functioning after selecting elements on each dropdown and clicking an apply button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just made dropdowns that have their respective elements. What I want is to select an element on each dropdown and after clicking the apply button they can't be edited anymore unless the edit button is clicked in turn the user can edit the dropdowns again using jquery

I just tried

```
document.getElementById("dropdown").disabled = true;
```

After clicking the button the dropdown is disabled. Is there any better way to do this.

Comment: Define better. What's wrong with disabling the dropdown?

Comment: In a more presentable manner I guess where the dropdown arrow actually disappears but if there isn't any then it is fine

Comment: Then I don't think you can do anything smarter than manually create replacement elements (like properly styled `<span>` or `<p>`) next to the inputs/selects and hide the selects. Possibly you can have them created all the time and just update visibility, e.g. by toggling a class on the form. Alternatively, use a framework/library that would do that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use library**

Perhaps the best answer is "get a UI library that will do that for you". For example, Bootstrap has [`.form-control-plaintext`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#readonly-plain-text) class that may be just what you need. Other libraries have similar possibilities.

I could just end here, but the question is tagged jQuery, so there is also pure jQuery solution (that can be easily simplified to vanilla JS):

**Create replacements by hand**

If you want to use standard input or select elements, one solution is to just have some placeholders next to them and toggle the visibility according to the need.

Your solution could look roughly like this:

First, add `<span>` placeholders next to inputs in your html, and add some wrappers for simpler access from JS:

```
<div id="form-wrapper">
  <div class="input-pack">
    <input value="Hello World">
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="select-pack">
    <select>
      <option value="first" selected>First Value</option> 
      <option value="second">Second Value</option>
    </select>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <button>Toggle freeze</button>
</div>
```

Next, write JS code for updating the placeholders and toggling the wrapper class. Leveraging jQuery abilities and ES6 syntax makes it pretty concise:

```
button.on("click", function(){
  // Update text in input placeholders
  $("#form-wrapper .input-pack").each((i, pack) => {
    $("span", pack).text($("input", pack).val());
  });
  // Update text in select placeholders
  $("#form-wrapper .select-pack").each((i, pack) => {
    $("span", pack).text($("select option:selected", pack).text());
  });
  // Actually toggle visibility
  wrapper.toggleClass("frozen");
});
```

Finally, add CSS to hide and show fields depending on the wrapper class:

```
#form-wrapper .input-pack span,
#form-wrapper .select-pack span,
#form-wrapper.frozen .input-pack input,
#form-wrapper.frozen .select-pack select {
  display: none;
}

#form-wrapper.frozen .input-pack span,
#form-wrapper.frozen .select-pack span {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black; /* add your own style*/
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/g527x1ae/

However, well, a library is usually a better idea.

Comment: thanks a lot! seems this one is what i'm looking for. Also gonna try bootstrap

Comment: Hi @Onjieee, if my answer was helpful, you can consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).